# How can I Access a Github Project with a Private Key?

Tags: github

For example,
I'm given a private key named `p_key`, and I copy it to the directory as follows

```
cp p_key ~/.ssh/
```

In the ~/.ssh/config file, it writes as

```
host someHost
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/p_key 
hostName someHost
```

I also make `p_key` private. When I tried

```
ssh gitosis@someHost
```

It should work with an empty password, but it keeps telling me that

```
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Private key is in pair with a public key. The private key is placed under .ssh folder and the public key need to be set in the github profile account settings under SSH keys section. Here is a link to their documentation on how to do this. 
https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/